# How do I get Selenium to open an HTTPS URL with a real cert?

Tags: python, selenium, https

I'm attempting to use selenium to automate some browser-based data entry.  The target URL is HTTPS, but it's an actual public website and not a self-signed cert.  I'm running the following code:

```
from selenium import selenium
import unittest, time, re

class python_2_remote_control(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.selenium = selenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "https://actualurl")
        self.selenium.start()

    def test_python_2_remote_control(self):
        sel = self.selenium
        sel.type("id=loginid", "etc.")
        more...
```

The proxy loads, but the actual URL never seems to load in it, any my first command to login fails.  Any sense of what could be failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your https requires a certificate you will need an own selenium firefox profile which accepted the certificate.

Google how to use custom firefox profiles within selenium.

The server command line:

```
java -jar selenium-server.jar -log SeleniumServer.log -firefoxProfileTemplate "C:\ffprofile" -trustAllSSLCertificates
```